# Found Nil with date picker in reusable cell while using date

Tags: swift, datepicker, tablecell

I got the following code:

```
  var cell = DatePickerTableViewCell()

func updateDueDateLabel() {
cell.dueDateLabel.text = dueDateFormatter.string(from: cell.dueDatePickerView.date) 
}   

let dueDateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-YYYY"
    return formatter
    }()
```

with cell being:

```
class DatePickerTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
@IBOutlet var dueDatePickerView: UIDatePicker!
@IBOutlet var dueDateLabel: UILabel! }
```

where the date picker and label is in a reusable cell

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
if indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 1 {
  cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "datePicker") as! DatePickerTableViewCell
}
if indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0 {
  cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "label") as! DatePickerTableViewCell
  cell.selectionStyle = .none
}
return cell
}
```

when I try to call the function updateDueDateLabel I get an error message that it found nil while unwrapping and I can't figure out what is wrong. the cell.dueDateLabel is working so it is something with either the formatter or the datepicker that gives the error.

The table, the label and the datepicker does show on screen if I comment of the func to update the label

Comment: Is your label connected to the storyboard? If it is you need to show the rest of your `tableViewCell` code. Also what is `cell` in your `updateDueDateLabel` method?

Comment: Not related but your date format is presumably wrong. It's supposed to be `yyyy` unless you really mean the week based calendar.

Comment: Where is your method `updateDueDateLabel` located? And where are you calling it?

Comment: it is located within my class, and I am calling it from view did load

Answer (score 0):

You have two custom cells: `datePicker` and `label`. But it is confusing since in your definition of `DatePickerTableViewCell` this type of cell has both a date picker and a label.

Before trying to change `cell.dueDateLabel.text` you have to make sure that `cell` is the one with the UILabel.

And, make sure that the datePicker view is loaded before trying to its text.

Comment: Good point, that was however not the problem, I tried with a label outside of the tableview and tried to set it = dueDateFormatter.string(from: cell.dueDatePickerView.date), but it stilled crashes

Answer (score 0):

I seem to found the error, I changed the place I called the function from viewdidload to after the cells have loaded, I assume this was because the datepicker had not loaded yet.